# Recursion With Memory Allocation

Tags: c, recursion, memory-management, heap-memory

I was watching a video about CUDA and the Barnes-Hut algorithm where it was stated that it is necessary to place a depth limit on the tree for the GPU, and then the idea popped into my head about possibly doing recursion in the heap.

Basically, I am wondering just that: Is it possible to allocate memory from the heap and use that as a temporary "stack" in which to place function calls for the recursive function in question to somewhat delay a stack overflow?

If so, how could it be implemented, would we allocate space for a pointer to the function? I assume it would involve storing function address in the heap however I'm not too sure.

[edit] I just wanted to add that this is purely a theoretical question, and i would imagine that doing this would cause the program to slow down once using the heap.

[edit] As per request, the compiler I am using is GCC 4.8.4 on Ubuntu 14.04 (64-bit)

Comment: C does not define any such mechanism.  In fact, it does not define "stack" or "heap" at all, under those or any other names.  They are standard names for aspects of most *implementations*, but they are outside the scope of C.  On one hand, that means you'll need to specify a particular implementation to get a useful answer.  On the other hand, it also means that C itself does not forbid what you describe.  On the third hand, I'm not aware of any implementation that provides it.

Comment: @JohnBollinger Sorry, I don't quite get what you mean when saying I'll need to specify a particular implementation. Do you mean how the language itself deals with the memory? I've only taken a few introductory courses so far and haven't gotten into this side of things other than the basics of how the C compiler (and i guess most compilers) manage the memory.

Comment: "Specifying a particular implementation" means narrowing the scope of the question to something like GCC 5 / glibc on Linux, or MS Visual C++ 2013 on Windows 10.

Comment: @JohnBollinger Done, thanks I didn't think of that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sure.  This is called continuation-passing style.  The standard library supports it with `setjmp()` and `longjmp()`, and stores the information needed to restore control to an earlier point in a structure called `jmp_buf`.  (There are several restrictions on where you can restore from.)  You would store them in a stack, which is just a LIFO queue.

A more general approach is to run the program as a state machine and store the information needed to backtrack the program state, called a continuation, in a data structure called a trampoline.  A common reason to want to do this is to get the equivalent of tail-recursion in an implementation that doesn’t optimize it and might chew up lots of stack space.  One real-world application where someone I know is currently writing a trampoline is a GLL parser where the grammar is represented as a directed graph, the result of the parse is a shared packed parse forest, and the parser often needs to backtrack to try a different rule.

Continuation-passing and trampolines seem to be regarded as fancy style because they come from the world of functional programming, while `longjmp()` is regarded as an ugly low-level hack and even the Linux man page says not to use it.

Comment: I don't think continuations really address the question posed, as they do not alter what the system uses for a stack for subsequent calls, neither in the direct code nor in the continuation.  In the event that a continuation is desired, however, it's important to note that `setjmp()` / `longjmp()` support them only in a limited way, for once control leaves the function that called `setjmp()`, the behavior of a corresponding longjmp is no longer defined.

Comment: It’s an alternative means of control flow from function calls and returns. That said, your comment about `longjmp()` is not correct: the behavior is undefined if the original function *has exited*, not as soon as control leaves it. It is legal to `longjmp()` from a function called recursively by the one that also called `setjmp()`. In fact, that was the use case for which `goto` was not enough.

Comment: By "control leaves" I indeed meant that the function returns or exits by calling `longjmp()`, as opposed to calling (other) functions.  Anyway, the OP's question is specifically about using a different region of memory for the call stack.  Inasmuch as continuations are an *alternative* to call / return, for that very reason they do not address the question.

Comment: @JohnBollinger I disagree.  The question was, ‘Is it possible to allocate memory from the heap and use that as a temporary "stack" in which to place function calls for the recursive function …?’  Trampolines, which I discussed in my second paragraph, do exactly this.  Continuation-passing is closely-related and equivalent, especially when used to implement tail-recursion. It’s a common way to do what the OP wants, so I thought it would be helpful to point in that direction.

Answer (score 1):

You can simulate this by implementing your own heap-based stack as an array of structures, with each structure representing a stack frame that holds the equivalent of parameters and local variables. Instead of a function calling itself recursively, the function loops and each "call" explicitly pushes a new frame onto the stack.

I did exactly this years ago while attempting to solve a simple board game. The program was originally recursive, and it took forever to run. I changed it to the above structure, and this made it simple to make the app interruptible/restartable. When interrupted the app dumped its "stack" to a state file. When restarted, the app loaded the state file and continued where it left off.

This does required some care if the stack frame structure contains embedded pointers, but it's not insurmountable.